# Rails: Link_to raw(' ') when adding to another element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my view I would like to have `Post.find..` before the `raw` as in the second example below. The `raw` is there because I'm using a separate font inline that I need to detect with css.

Putting the `raw` before the Post: this renders properly. However it's not the sequence I want.

```
<%= link_to raw("<span id='arrow'>&gt</span>") + Post.find_by_id(post.id-1).title, params.merge(:page => @posts.previous_page) %>
```

This doesn't work, the raw gets rendered like, `"<span id='arrow'>&gt</span>"`. But it is the sequence I want.

```
<%= link_to Post.find_by_id(post.id-1).title + raw("<span id='arrow'>&gt</span>"), params.merge(:page => @posts.previous_page) %>
```

How can I get the second statement to render the `raw` properly?

Comment: You really ought to not put calls to find in your views.  You probably want a helper or something that renders this instead of making a mess in ERB.  Also, `post.id - 1` isn't going to work for the first post, and also isn't necessarily always going to work.  Deleting a post, for example, will cause it to fail.

Comment: hi brandon :)

Thanks, I'll end up refactoring the view code into model helpers at some point. Yup good catch on the post.id -1. I'll need to refactor that one too. 

How's everything in A^2? If you make it out to SF let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%= link_to raw("#{Post.find_by_id(post.id-1).title} <span id='arrow'>&gt</span>"), params.merge(:page => @posts.previous_page) %>
```